# Suing Microsoft for automatically restarting my PC when windows has updates

Tags: internet, property

Is there anything in the EU law (or the law of any EU state) that permits suing Microsoft for auto restarting my PC each time there is a windows update (and not allowing me to prevent this)?
My PC is my property and I should be the one that decides what to do with it.

Comment: And if MS didn't auto-restart, people would be suing them for failing to ensure the security of the operating system. Windows already offers a variety of features to prevent restarts at unexpected times, such as by performing the restart outside of your Active Hours (in a home context) or through group policies (in a business context).

Comment: What financially quantifiable damages were suffered as a result?

Comment: Did you read terms of services thoroughly?? Windows is certainly not your property you're just licensed to use that.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere Damages: work lost (ex: rendering, takes a lot of time) because windows decided to restart my PC in the middle of if. Time lost to restore the entire work environment after the unexpected restart. Each time MS decides its time to restart my PC.

Comment: @ShivCK Windows is not my property but my PC is.  I know that I've accepted the term, like I have any other option if I have to work with clients that require tools that only work on windows :) 2. Updates are one thing, force restarting my PC is another thing.

Comment: Why the down vote? Is this not a legit question?

Comment: You might have more luck asking on Superuser about how to control these updates.

Comment: @user39137 By the same argument you have a claim against your rendering software provider: if the software were to take regular checkpoints, an unexpected restart or crash wouldn't lead to substantial lost time. Also, note that updates cannot take effect without restarting the system. Many Windows updates are extremely urgent security updates. Losing work because of a restart is better than losing work due to a virus.

Comment: @amon By the same argument if I get shot on the street and die, it is my fault because I did not wear protective armor, and not the fault of the one that pulled the trigger :)

Comment: @amon "updates cannot take effect without restarting the system" - As a Linux user I'd have to disagree with you here! It's a design choice rather than an inherent limitation.

Comment: You didn't consent to being shot. You did consent to updates.

Comment: @JBentley It's the same on Linux, largely. Only few programs such as systemd can update without losing state. An application update (such as for your web browser) will require a restart of the browser. An X server or desktop environment update will require a restart of your session. A kernel update does require a restart of the kernel, though live patching can be used in some cases. On Windows, the different file system model adds additional complications (can't write a file while it is in use). Yes it's a design choice, but the design was not chosen out of incompetence or negligence.

Comment: @amon Agreed, but the point is on Linux you are not compelled to restart the entire machine. You can restart specific applications or services and doing so generally takes a very short time (~1 second). But in any case my comment was just an aside and I didn't mean to detract from your point as it pertains to the legal question. I agree it doesn't imply any culpability on the part of Microsoft.

Answer (score 7):

Anyone can sue anyone for anything- you don't need a law that says "user39137 is allowed to sue Microsoft for restarting his PC". The question is whether you will succeed.

You won't, for two reasons. Three if you count the fact that it's trivial to stop updates restarting your PC at inconvenient times.

First, you probably agreed to this in [the EULA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm).

> Updates. The softwareperiodically (sic) checks for system and app updates, and downloads and installs them for you. You may obtain updates only from Microsoft or authorized sources, and Microsoft may need to update your system to provide you with those updates. By accepting this agreement, you agree to receive these types of automatic updates without any additional notice.
>
> Windows 10 EULA

This likely isn't the only bit where you accept this, but it's the best I could find by skimming with ctrl-f. Obviously if you were to start a lawsuit, you'd want to read the whole thing.

Second, to sue someone you need to have suffered damages. "Being annoyed because the computer restarted in the middle of Among Us" isn't really worth anything.

Comment: 1. I know that I've accepted the term, like I have any other option if I have to work with clients that require tools that only work on windows :) 2. Updates are one thing, force restarting my PC is another thing. 3. Damages: work lost (ex: rendering, takes a lot of time) because windows decided to restart my PC in the middle of if. Time lost to restore the entire work environment after the unexpected restart.

Comment: @user39137 The fact that you choose to use tools that require Windows does not invalidate the agreement. If using Windows is impractical, use a different operating system.

Comment: I agree that the OP would probably not succeed. But the reasons gloss over quite a lot of nuances. (1) Not everything that is in a contract is enforceable - they are subject to all sorts of rules of statute and common law and in particular consumer protection laws can have quite a complicated effect. (2) "to sue someone you need to have suffered damages" - might be correct here, but definitely incorrect as a generalisation. Damages is just one remedy out of many others available in the courts e.g. financial remedies available by statute, rescission, injunction, etc.

Comment: @JBentley: Do you have a source for that? I've always understood that you need to have suffered damages (which need not be monetary) in order to have standing to sue. In the context of restitution, civil law focuses on damages because its goal is to establish equity, but, as you state there are other punitive or preventative measures that it can also inflict.

Comment: It is easy to image a case where there are damages, but the EULA also waives a right to recover for damages of that type.

Comment: @sharur I think there is some confusion on terminology here. [Damages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damages) by definition is a monetary award which the court grants as a remedy for a loss. However the court can give a monetary award even where there is no loss. See [Sections 214 of the Housing Act 2004](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/section/214) (and in particular 214(4)) for an example - the entitlement is automatic and triggered merely by the landlord breaching the legal requirement, regardless of whether the tenant suffered a loss.

Comment: @sharur Or consider the tort of [tresspass to land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_land) where the remedy is a prohibitory injuction whcih is actionable per se (regardless of loss).

Comment: @JBentley: I agree there is a confusion in terminology. I believe my (mis?)belief stems from the use of "damage(s)" in a common meaning, as a synonym for "harm" or "injury", which is required for [standing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_(law)), which as I apparently failed to adequately explain need not be monetary in nature. E.g. In section 214, the harm/damage suffered is non-compliancy with an authorized scheme regarding the lease deposit, while in the case of trespass, the harm is the infringement of the owner's property rights to allow or restrict access to the land.

Comment: @sharur The answer (and a further example) is in the 3rd bullet point of ways to achieve standing in the Wikipedia article you linked: "The party is granted automatic standing by act of law. Under some environmental laws in the United States, a party may sue someone causing pollution to certain waterways without a federal permit, even if the party suing is not harmed by the pollution being generated". in section 214 or trespass to land, those are not harms, they are [causes of action](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cause_of_action).

Comment: @sharur In law we use the phrase "[actionable per se](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/actionable-per-se)" to describe causes of action where you do not have to show any loss. A claim under section 214 is actionable per se. The fact that a 3rd party breached a legal requirement doesn't imply any loss to me - I might not care at all that they breached it. I might not have even been aware that they did so until years later when a lawyer tells me and even then it might seem to me to be a ridiculous technicality. Nonethless, I am entitled to sue for the award.